# How to give admin access to all user's mail

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, domain

I have setup a mail account using Google Apps. Everything is working fine except I want to  give the admin account access to all incoming an outgoing mail.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

There is an [auditing API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-audit/) available in Business, Education and ISP accounts that will allow you to download the contents of a user's GMail account including spam, sent and deleted items.

Google doesn't provide a GUI for it, but some third-party software, such as [Appogee DMS, does](http://www.appogee.co.uk/products/dms/auditing).

Answer (score 3):

You can not do this in Google Apps.  You have to login to each account using the specified username and password.  You can change the password but there is no way to access everyones mail unless you forward a copy from the users accounts.

Answer (score 1):

For delegation ...
Remember delegation needs to be enabled in the first place.
Admin Console> Google Apps> Settings for Gmail> User Settings> "Mail Delegation"

FlashPanel allows administrators to delegate rights from any user to any other user.
www.flashpanel.com

Related issues/solutions:

If you are just wanting to know what comes in to another user's account, there is always the mail rewrite rule (Admin Console> Google Apps> Settings for Gmail> User Settings>) .... where I say "If to {regexp}, copy to {another address}, optionally with [Via Fred] prepended in the subject".

The "Vault" (with Google Apps Unlimited) gives administrators ability to review anything

There is the audit report that lets you seach for emails in or out  with subject lines, MsgIDs, etc.  This can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Google has not yet built any back-end support for the administrator to trace Gmail messages within the Google Workspace administrator console.

If you need full access to other user's Gmail messages history I Highly Recommend you to use the Gmail Reader add-ons, These Google Workspace add-ons built for Google Workspace administrators will instantly grant Gmail admins unrestricted access, allow admins to search and view private messages history of any Gmail account without know or reset the account password.

See at [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/ez_gmail_reader/1060242446754).
See this addon [website](https://easyadm.com/apps/gmail-reader/index).

Answer (score 0):

We purchased our Google Apps licenses through Promevo.  Their gPanel allows me to "delegate" access for any email to ANY user.  Once set, the admin can easily view an individuals mailbox.  We originally started out without Promevo but transferred our licenses over when we discovered the gPanel was included with no additional cost.  We now renew at $50 per user per year through Promevo.  I guess they get a cut from Google. Win-Win.  The admin controls and support have been outstanding.

Comment: How does this work with an existing Google Apps account?

Answer (score 0):

1. Email Delegation won't work here, as your users will come to know about it.
2. Google vault is ideally best solution for it IF you have G Suite business SKU.
3. However, if you are on G Suite basic, you may consider following solution-:

I won't comment on why you would like to view their emails without understanding the context, but in terms of possibility, absolutely, you can get a bcc copy of your (all or some) users emails without them knowing it or without requiring their password.

Here is an old video that I have on this, and here is the step by step documentation with screenshots -: [G Suite Admin Login as another user](https://www.goldyarora.com/how-you-can-access-your-users-email-without-knowing-their-password-in-google-apps/)

Above video shows how to get bcc for users all emails, but you can even make it more granular by tweaking the rule, for e.g - send bcc only if header or body matches any specific word/s or Regex.

4. In case if your requirement is not fulfilled by above, you may consider putting a custom solution based on your needs with [Google's Email Audit API.](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/) You also don't need to start from scratch here, if you know a bit of Google Apps Script, you can use [this OAuth 2 library](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) on GitHub to easily use Audit API within Apps Script.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to set up an account and have all other incoming and outgoing mail forwarded to it.

When you login to that account there is a copy of all emails and you can use the search functions to find emails that you require. :)